fflush(stdin) not working and letting a loop continue
Here's the code
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void showBalance(double balance);
double deposit();
double withdraw(double balance);

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    double bal = 0;

    std::cout << "************ Banking ************\n";

    do
    {

        std::cout << "Welcome to your bank acount! Choose one of the following\n";
        std::cout << "1. Deposit\n";
        std::cout << "2. Withdraw\n";
        std::cout << "3. Show balance\n";
        std::cout << "4. Exit\n";

        std::cin >> choice;

        std::cin.clear();
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: bal += deposit();
                    showBalance(bal);
                    break;
            case 2: bal -= withdraw(bal);
                    showBalance(bal);
                    break;
            case 3: showBalance(bal);
                    break;
            case 4: std::cout << "Thanks for visiting!\n";
                    std::cout << "*******************************\n";
                    break;
            default: std::cout << "Invalid output";

        }
    } while (choice != 4);
    
        


    return 0;
}

void showBalance(double balance)
{
    std::cout << "You have $" << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << balance << " in your account\n";
}

double deposit()
{
    double deposit;

    std::cout << "How much would you like to deposit?: ";
    std::cin >> deposit;

    if(deposit > 0)
    {
        return deposit;
    }else{
        std::cout << "That's not a valid amount\n";
        return 0;
    }

    
}

double withdraw(double balance)
{
    double withdraw;

    std::cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?: ";
    std::cin >> withdraw;

    if(withdraw > balance)
    {
        std::cout << "Insufficient Balance! \n";
    }

    return withdraw;
}

I was following a practice for a bank program and it showed that I can use fflush(stdin) to avoid an infinite loop but when I tried it just kept repeating
I tried to reload and move to a different file and the problem persisted and then I retyped it only to continue having the same issue

fflush(stdin) is simply wrong.  "For input streams (and for update streams on which the last operation was input), the behavior is undefined." (source).  You want std::cin.ignore.

How to use fflush(stdin) in C++

Unfortunately, the "practice for a bank program" you are using is encouraging an approach that is not guaranteed to work.  fflush() on an input stream gives undefined behaviour according to the C (and therefore C++) standards.   fflush() does flush input streams on some platforms with some compilers (or their libraries), but there are platforms where that simply doesn't work.    Since it is not always clear what (or how!) platforms/compilers/libraries (or, worse, particular versions of those) do support flushing an input stream, it is better to avoid that entirely.

Don't keep your money in that bank.

It's a kind bank that lets you withdraw a negative amount. I would start with -1000 at the ATM and see how rich I can get.
